# How to display on button hover in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a bootstrap popover already present.  It need to display on hover.
Here is the result showing right now :

[image]

In red color button see light outline of red color, its done when button clicked. What i need is, when mouse hover on red or green button it should high light like screenshot of red button highlighted.

Here is the code i used:

```
<button type="button" class="btn {{.Status | statusButtonClass}} btn-circle" 
data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="{{.Status}}">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
</button>

.btn-circle.btn-lg::hover {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   padding: 10px 16px;
   font-size: 18px;
   line-height: 1.33;
   border-radius: 25px;
}
.btn-circle:hover { 
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 6px 0;
   font-size: 12px;
   line-height: 1.428571429;
   border-radius: 25px;
   opacity: 1;
   border-width: 3px;
}
```

In .statusButtonClass, I am getting value of color. Default.json file status is terminating ten red color, if its running then color is green.  class="btn {{.Status | statusButtonClass}} btn-circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see code below:

```css
.button {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
}
.button:hover {
border: 9px solid pink;
 opacity:0.8;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"></button>
```

**For your comment** 
I use css variabels:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables 
**And declare new pipe to border-color calls:**`statusButtonBorderColor`

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--color);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
}
.button:hover {
border: 9px solid var(--borderColor);
 opacity:0.8;
}
```

**Example for CSS variables:**

```css
    .button {
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: var(--color);
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        border: none;
    }
    .button:hover {
    border: 9px solid var(--borderColor);
     opacity:0.8;
    }
```

```html
<button class="button" style="--color:red;--borderColor:pink"></button>
```

Comment: hello again! tell if you need more help\

Comment: Hey, actually colors value ll get from .status json

Comment: and the color when  hover also?

Comment: you have to do it in jquery/javascript

Comment: hey, i have updated question can you check it.. ANy updates

Comment: Hey thanks for answer!!. Is it possible declare class="btn {{.Status | statusButtonClass}} btn-circle" in style. Then only i can get exact result

Comment: what you get `{{.Status | statusButtonClass}}` for example?

Comment: Will get status button color . In default.json file Status: Termination . mean red color else its running: green color.

Comment: in pipe `|` you declare the color?

Comment: Yes,  exactly .Status | statusButtonClass

Comment: so fine you dont need the class any more use my code

Comment: Is it correct .btn-circle{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: var(--color);
  
}
.btn-circle:hover {
/* border: 9px solid var(--color); */
box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 4pt var(--color);
opacity:0.8;
}

Comment: look like that yes

Comment: But i am getting result like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4Fv2Lhy2idwl0EES27fdZRWZr09ZG3F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: so use as I do and declare color to border(if red declare pink) in anoter pipe

Comment: Sorry i did not get you

Comment: `--borderColor:{{.Status | statusButtonBorderColor }}` make new pipe call `statusButtonBorderColor` that return the color of `border`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a box-shadow on hover and this will achieve the look you want.

```
.btn-circle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.btn-danger{  
  background-color:red;  
  border-color: red;
}

.btn-danger:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 4pt #f47f90;
}
```

You can apply `.btn-danger` via json (or whatever you wish to call it)

More details on box-shadow can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

I have also created a [pen](https://codepen.io/Layla-P/pen/dedpQq).

Comment: hey, i am not any color value in css. I am getting from json

Comment: So you could create a class for each hover color such as .statusButtonClass-danger:hover{box-shadow: 0 0 1pt 4pt #f47f90;} and apply the class via json that way.

Comment: I have updated my answer and the codepen to reflect this.